# Beginner looking at Sails, not seeing big picture

Tags: architecture, frameworks, sails.js

As a beginner looking at Sails, I see simple examples leading one through, but see nothing that tells me what is actually happening in this framework.  Thus, I don't see where I would add a new page or change a layout, etc.  When a Java program or servlet is called, I can see exactly where it starts, where it services events, etc. and how they are handled.  PHP, most other systems, the same way.

So, what is the architecture of Sails?  A diagram showing what's on the server, how the application one creates is started and how it gets events and services them.  What is the structure of a page?  What affects the layout?  If I want to have 3 buttons on the bottom of the page that lead to other pages, how do I do that?

I have an existing MySQL database.  Can I generate a CRUD application for it as I can in Ruby on Rails?  Show me.

Very difficult to see how to actually do useful work, not just play around, when there are only trivial examples that don't usually work and if you make any changes, you have to delete everything and start completely over!  To be useful, you have to know where things are and if something is not working, where to look to fix it.  You have to grok the system!

Comment: We are really here to answer specific questions, rather than just "Tell me how to use Sails". If you have a specific question, feel free to ask it.

Comment: Appreciate your wanting to use Sails!  This isn't a great question for StackOverflow.  Luckily there's plenty of [documentation](http://sailsjs.org).  Your questions about layout and views should have answers in the [views documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/views) (in the end, it's HTML, like Rails or any other web framework).  Similar documentation exists for [command line generation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/command-line-interface) of [CRUD interfaces](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other commenters have said, this is not the right format of question for stack overflow.

However I'll point you in the right direction. Have a look at a few of Irl Nathan's Sailscasts here: http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/archives/

They helped me get my head around the various concepts. Alternatively take a look through the files in a new sails project. The comments do an excellent job of explaining what goes where.